# Where clause is not fetching correct data in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get all articles which have 'approved' value in status column. Here is the code:

```
$articles = Article::where('status', 'approved')->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->get();
```

But I am getting all data. where clause is not working! Is there anything wrong with the Syntax?

Edit 1:
Here is the what I'm getting for the query:

[image]

Edit 2: 
Here are the columns I used in table.

[image]

Comment: Your syntax is working fine in my machine. I think your problem is in your datas.

Comment: try adding "=" in your where clause like these `Article::where('status', '=', 'approved')->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: @escbooster12 I don't think adding "=" make any difference here ? both give same result.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli hmm.. my bad sorry. If so, Mosharof Zito try to check in your database if there is really 'approved' data in status column.

Comment: @escbooster12 and Md.Sukel Ali please check the edit of the question. I have added the output in an image.

Comment: @MosharofZitu ahh I see.. bro can I see list of columns in your Article table?

Comment: @escbooster12 I have added column list in the question. Please check.

Comment: @MosharofZitu yeah yeah, that is your created column in your Article model. What I mean bro is the actual database, could you go to your phpmyadmin or sqlog and screenshot the Article table's structure, like these https://www.google.com/search?q=sample+database+structure+phpmyadmin&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6mP_yt5rhAhWJQY8KHT7EDksQ_AUIDigB&biw=1024&bih=625#imgdii=FMDqF9MuyKTkXM:&imgrc=3aVhkfYX9zC8EM:[link]